# Как отправлять сообщения программой msg.exe?

Tags: windows, сервер

Нужна помощь.

Windows Server 2012 находится в рабочей группе.
На нем развернут терминальный сервер.

Необходимо, дать возможность пользователю (без админских прав) отправлять сообщения всем пользователям, подключенным к терминальному серверу.

Погуглил, нашел, что можно из консоли запускать программу msg.exe.
Программа работает, но сообщение не доходят до пользователей (нет прав)

Как разрешить отправку сообщений пользователя (без адмниских прав) через программу msg.exe всем пользователям?

Спасибо за помощь.

Comment: 'Net send' вроде работало раньше

Comment: @eri Начиная с Vista, -  не работает

Answer (score 2):

MSG не требует многого. Обычно ей для работы нужны три вещи:
1. Открытый TCP порт 445 (правда, [бывают проблемы](https://support.microsoft.com/ru-kz/help/4471134/smb-sharing-not-accessible-when-tcp-port-445-listening-in-windows-serv) )
2. Разрешенный AllowRemoteRPC

Для этого проверяем, установлено ли значение параметра **AllowRemoteRPC** в ветке `HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Terminal Server` в 1. Если нет, изменяем и перегружаемся.

3. Пользователь должен иметь привилегии для отправки сообщений:

Открываем Конфигуратор сервера узла сеансов рабочих столов (проще всего tsconfig.msc из консоли) и добавляем права пользователей именно так, как я показал на скриншоте:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Update 1**

В случае, если у вас версия Server 2012 R2 (в нём нет описываемой оснастки сразу) или поздний релиз Server 2012, в котором они тоже отключены (речь идёт о стандартных оснастках tsadmin.msc (Remote Desktop Services Manager, по-русски Диспетчер служб удаленных рабочих столов) и tsconfig.msc (Remote Desktop Session Host Configuration, по-русски Конфигурация узла сеансов удаленных рабочих столов), то можно использовать Server Manager или консоль редактора групповых политик (gpedit.msc), но там всё несколько, на мой взгляд, замороченнее.

Обычно поступают по-иному: возвращают эти две оснастки, используя библиотеки от Server 2012, где они есть, ли даже от Server 2008.

Всё, что нужно сделать, это скопировать в папку C:\Windows\System32 вашего сервера соответствующие файлы оснастки:

```
c:\windows\system32\tsadmin.dll
c:\windows\system32\tsconfig.dll
c:\windows\system32\wts.dll
c:\windows\system32\tsconfig.msc
c:\windows\system32\tsadmin.msc
c:\windows\system32\en\tsconfig.resources.dll
c:\windows\system32\en\tsadmin.resources.dll
```

И сделать экспорт соответствующих веток реестра

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\MMC\SnapIns\FX:{80aaa290-abd9-9239-7a2d-cf4f67e42128}
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\MMC\SnapIns\FX:{3FCE72B6-A31B-43ac-ADDA-120E1E56EB0F}
```

с последующим импортом.

Мы уже проделывали подобную операцию, она недеструктивна, но не у всех есть под рукой установленные серверы с рабочими оснастками. Поэтому вот комплекты (файлы + реестр) для [английского](https://github.com/vicontfreetime/server2012-msc/blob/master/tsadmin-win2012.zip) и  [русского](https://github.com/vicontfreetime/server2012-msc/blob/master/tsadmin-win2012_ru.zip) серверов 2012/2012 R2.

**Update 2**

В принципе, как следует [из официальной справки](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/win32/termserv/win32-tsaccount-modifypermissions?redirectedfrom=MSDN), мы можем управлять данными разрешениями из WMI. Стоит лишь сделать выборку всех пользователей входящих в группу Remote Desktop Users и выставить в параметрах седьмой бит в единицу, как следует из справки. Можно набросать программу на Delphi или C#, но проще запустить powershell'овский скрипт, примерно вот такой:

```
$acc = @(Get-WmiObject -Namespace Root\CIMv2\TerminalServices -Query "SELECT * FROM Win32_TSAccount WHERE TerminalName='RDP-TCP' AND AccountName='BUILTIN\\Remote Desktop Users'") 
# обратились к Win32_TSAccount, сделали выборку всех пользователей терминалов
Foreach($account In $acc)
{
    $account.ModifyPermissions(7,1) 
# устанавливаем седьмой бит в единицу

}
```

P.S. В принципе, можно всё запихать в powershell'овский скрипт:

- Открытие порта (можно через netsh)
- Проверка наличия ключа в реестре и его изменение/создание
- установка привилегий

Comment: Здравствуйте.
Первый два пункта выполнил.
Последний пункт в Windows Server 2012 нету. 
Нет утилиты tsconfig.msc.

Comment: Конфигуратор сервера узла сеансов рабочих столов я не нашел.

Comment: У вас R2 или поздняя редакция Server 2012? Ясно, сейчас дополню ответ.

Comment: Установлен Windows Server 2012 Standard.

Comment: Подскажите, как можно сделать через редактор групповых политик (gpedit.msc)?

Comment: @pavel увы, со вчера в командировке, и надолго. Доступа к серверу в ближайшее время не будет, а без него так сразу и не вспомнить

Comment: @pavel Но вы всегда можете попробовать использовать WMI для управления. Сейчас попробую набросать...

Comment: @pavel Скрипт работает - коллега по моей просьбе только что проверил :) Не забудьте запускать от админа и разрешить выполнение скриптов, в принципе.